# Using jquery method .find() inside object declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I'm new to js object and I'm trying to write a simple plugin in jQuery but I have problems to declare properties. 
Look at this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rb3funnL/) for a better highlighted code

```
$.fn.robertSlider = function(params){
    var slider = {
        arrow:              this.find(".slider-arrow"),
        arrowNext:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowNext"),
        arrowPrev:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowPrev"),
        sliderItem:         this.find(".slider-item"),
        sliderList:         this.find(".slider-content-list"),

        itemsOnScreen:      params.itemsOnScreen,
        marginCollapse:     params.marginCollapse
    };

    slider.amountItems      = slider.sliderItem.length; // is there a way to declare this directly inside the obj?
    slider.sliderWidth      = slider.sliderList.width(); // is there a way to declare this directly inside the obj?

    var helpers = {
        firstVisible:       0,
        canGoNext:          true,
        canGoPrev:          false
    }
}




$(".slider-container").robertSlider({
        itemsOnScreen:          6,
        marginCollapse:         10
});
```

Now my question is: what is wrong with this object declaration? 
Because if I try to log `slider.sliderWidth` it doesn't work, I get `null`. 
I tried to log `slider.sliderList` I get a complete different result as I log `$(".slider-content-list")`

**UPDATE** 
Here below the screenshot of the log between `slider.arrow` and `$(".slider-arrow")`

[image: Screenshot of console.log]

Hope everything is clear :) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "this" is correct.  Can you post the html inside of your fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `amountItems` or `sliderWidth` properties inside the object declaration because the property values won't be set yet as the object hasn't yet been declared.

For example it doesn't matter whether you have:

```
var a = {
  x: 1,
  y: a.x+1
};
```

Or:

```
var a = {
  y: a.x+1,
  x: 1
};
```

Neither will work because the object hasn't been declared yet.

With your example the following would work, but obviously includes code duplication / performance cost:

```
var slider = {
    arrow:              this.find(".slider-arrow"),
    arrowNext:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowNext"),
    arrowPrev:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowPrev"),
    sliderItem:         this.find(".slider-item"),
    sliderList:         this.find(".slider-content-list"),

    itemsOnScreen:      params.itemsOnScreen,
    marginCollapse:     params.marginCollapse,

    amountItems:        this.find(".slider-item").length,
    sliderWidth:        this.find(".slider-item").width()
};
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
var obj = {
    arrow:              this.find(".slider-arrow"),
    arrowNext:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowNext"),
    arrowPrev:          this.find(".slider-arrow--arrowPrev"),
    sliderItem:         this.find(".slider-item"),
    sliderList:         this.find(".slider-content-list"),
}

var slider = {
    arrow:              obj.arrow,
    arrowNext:          obj.arrowNext,
    arrowPrev:          obj.arrowPrev,
    sliderItem:         obj.sliderItem,
    sliderList:         obj.sliderList,

    itemsOnScreen:      params.itemsOnScreen,
    marginCollapse:     params.marginCollapse,

    amountItems:        obj.sliderItem.length,
    sliderWidth:        obj.sliderItem.width()
};
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation!. How can I fix it properly in terms of performance and stay DRY? :)

Comment: @dghez See my update. You could have an initial object which collects the element references, and then use that in your `slider` for all.

Comment: i'll give it a shot! I'll try asap. What about the difference of the stored values between the one in the obj and the one declared normally? See the my update with image

Comment: @dghez if you look at the selector of "slider.arrow" in your screenshot, it uses ".slider-container .arrow" instead of ".slider-arrow"  that is why it didn't find the arrow.

Comment: Damn, my bad. 
Btw I solved my problem, I was declaring the `slider obj` OUTSIDE of the doc.ready so it cannot get the width, of course. That's why I was getting null.